# Excel: Ignore the last value in series 1 if COUNT(series1) > COUNT(series2)

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, array

I am currently using excel to do some trading.  In one series I have a column of "buy prices" and the column next to it is "sell prices".

I want to divide all of my sell prices by all of my buy prices to make a quick percent.  However, I sometimes have one more buy price than sell prices. The extra buy price throws the percentage off a bit.

Is there a function that will ignore the last buy price in the "buy prices" column when finding the SUM of that column?   I will be replicating these hundreds of times using different strategies and really do not want to manually delete the last buy price.

Comment: how are you selecting your series?  With A:A or exact A1:A34 ?

Comment: "The extra buy price throws the percentage off a bit. " .. what's original formula for this?